# How to convert a decimal number into a binary one and insert all his binary digit into a 2d vector?

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, stl, binary

if the input is:

```
73 68 69 65
```

the output should look like this:

```
0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 ///73 in binary form
0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 ///68 in binary form
0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 ///69 in binary form
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 ///65 in binary form
```

The matrix has 8 columns as above, and each rows contains the binary form of the decimal number.

This is my code so far:

```
    int n, x;
    cin >> n;

    auto A = vector<vector<int>>(n, vector<int>(8)); ///8 columns as mentioned

    while (n--)
    {

        cin >> x;
        for (int j = 8; j >= 0; --j) ///inserting the digits for each number
            if ((x >> j) & 1)
                A[i].emplace_back(1);
            else
                A[i].emplace_back(0);
    }

    for (auto rows : A)
    {
        for (auto elements : rows)
            cout << elements << " ";
        cout << "\n";
    }
```

I tried using bitwise operation, but any method would be fine for me using `vector<vector<int>>`.

If you could answer it would be very appreciated, thank you for reading and answering!

Also a second problem, it shows me 16 digit 000000000001001001 instead of  01001001, lots of zero at the beginning If the input is 73 for example.

Comment: Care with shift and signed numbers

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Comment: *"This is my code so far:"* And do you have issue with it?

Comment: well It doesn t show me that when I compile it.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: for exemple for 65 it show me : 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1, wich is not good it should show me 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1

Comment: `i` != `j`, recheck their usage.

Comment: @Jarod42 thank you, but there also a second problem, it shows me 16 digit 000000000001001001, lots of zero at the beginning, which is didn t what I need

Comment: and you emplace_back into a vector which has already a size of 8...

Comment: You were already advised to use a debugger. The bug is very simple, and should be easily observed in a debugger. You should invest some time learning how to use a debugger, and learning how to find and fix bugs in your own code without having to ask anyone for help. Doesn't it make a lot of sense to do that, than to post questions to stackoverflow.com and wait hours, or days, every time your program doesn't work right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem behind your solution is that Int type is not store on one byte, I worked out a solution that fit you code.

Note: I store the input in an unsigned char that is store in one byte (instead of using an int), by doing so the input read from cin is a character, for example: '8', so considering the ASCII table I can get the number represented by the character subtracting 48 (see ASCII table for explanation):

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    unsigned char x;
    cin >> n;

    auto A = vector<vector<int> >(n); ///8 columns as mentioned

    while (n--)
    {
        cin >> x;
        x -= 48;
        auto aByte = vector<int>(8);

        for (int j = 0; j < 8 ; ++j) ///inserting the digits for each number
        {
            if ( (x >> j) & 0x01 )
                aByte[7 - j] = 1;
            else
                aByte[7 - j] = 0;
        }
         A[n] = aByte;
    }

    for (auto rows : A)
    {
        for (auto elements : rows)
            cout << elements << " ";
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

the above solution works only for one digit number, for more digits (but limited to one byte representation) you can cin to an int and then cast the int to an unsigned char, just replace these lines of code:

```
cin >> x;
x -= 48;
```

with these:

```
int i;
cin >> i;
x = static_cast<unsigned char>(i);
```